# Object reference not set to an instance of an object while using stored procedures

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

This is a .cs page and I have two function to be executed, But the error is both the function are not being executed ,if I comment on one function the other will work, both are not executed,it giving a common error `object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Below specified is a .cs page.

```
Business bus = new Business();

try
{
    intResult = bus.create_user(ua);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
finally
{
    bus = null;
}

int intres = 0;

try
{
    intres = bus.fninsertuser_role_map(ua, role, i);

}
catch (Exception ee)
{

}
finally
{
    bus = null;
}
```

Data access object

```
public int create_user(UserMaster ua)
{
    //  Connection connect = new Connection();
    try
    {
        return cs.create_user(ua);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
    finally
    {
        cs = null;
    }

}

public int fninsertuser_role_map(UserMaster ua, int[] role, int i)
{
    //  Connection connect = new Connection();
    try
    {
        return cs.fninsertuser_role_map(ua, role, i);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;//**Throws the exception here.**
    }
    finally
    {
        //cs = null;
    }
```

Business value object

```
public int create_user(UserMaster ua)
{
    SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(str);
    Con.Open();
    SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand("createuser", Con);
    Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    try
    {
        log.Debug("Inside Create user");
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User_Id", ua.UserName);
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", ua.Password);
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", ua.Name);
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Role_Id", ua.Role);
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Department_Id", ua.Department);
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Active", ua.Active);
        log.Debug("Inside Create_User: New User created having ID: " + ua.UserName);
        log.Info("user created");
        return Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        log.Debug("Error: Inside catch block of Create User");
        log.Error("Error msg:" + e);
        log.Error("Stack trace:" + e.StackTrace);

        throw e;
    }
    finally
    {
        Cmd.Dispose();
        Con.Close();
        Con.Dispose();
    }


}

/*Function to insert into user_role_map*/

public int fninsertuser_role_map(UserMaster u, int[] role, int i)
{
    SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(str);
    Con.Open();
    transaction = Con.BeginTransaction();
    int result = 0;


    for (int a = 0; a < i; a++)
    {
        SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand("create_UR_Map", Con, transaction);
        Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        Cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User_Id", u.UserName);
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Role_Id", role[a]);


        result = Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    transaction.Commit();

    return result;

}
```

I just need to execute both the function in the same page.Any help are appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Problem :** you are trying to put `null` into instance variable `bus` and then calling methods using the same variable as below:

```
try
{
    intResult = bus.create_user(ua);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
finally
{
    bus = null;//bus becomes null here for sure even if there is no excption thrown
}

int intres = 0;

try
{
    intres = bus.fninsertuser_role_map(ua, role, i);//throws exception here

}
```

that is why it throws `object reference not set to an instance of an object`.

**Note :** You should remember that `finally` block willbe executed irrespective of the situation means it will be executed in all the cases and your instance variable `bus` becomes `null` for sure even if there is no exception thrown.

**Solution :** i think you need to really refactor your code but your intension is to making instance variable `bus` to `null` if it throws exception if that is the case move that statement inside the catch block.

Try This:

```
try
{
    intResult = bus.create_user(ua);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    bus = null;
}
finally
{
    //any code which needs to be executed for sure
}

int intres = 0;

try
{
    intres = bus.fninsertuser_role_map(ua, role, i);

}
catch (Exception ee)
{
  bus = null;
}
finally
{
    //any code which needs to be executed for sure
}
```